# Vega-Lite chart x-axis display not displaying month after the start of the new year

Tags: vega-lite

I have a chart with dates in formatted as `yyyy-mm-dd` with a type of 'temporal'. It's also using a custom axis

```
chartAxis = {
  const obj = {};
  (obj.grid = false),
    (obj.tickCount = { interval: 'month', step: 1 }),
    (obj.labelAlign = 'left'),
    (obj.labelExpr = 'datum.label[0]');
  return obj;
}
```

Ever since the start of the year, instead of the displaying the first letter of the month, it started to display the first digit of the year.

I'm at a loss. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default date display chosen by Vega-Lite depends on the range of dates being displayed and the space between each label, and at year transitions it will often display the new year. Here is a simple example:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"date": "2020-10-31T00:00:00", "value": 9},
      {"date": "2020-11-30T00:00:00", "value": 10},
      {"date": "2020-12-31T00:00:00", "value": 11},
      {"date": "2021-01-31T00:00:00", "value": 12},
      {"date": "2021-02-28T00:00:00", "value": 13}
    ]
  },
  "mark": "line",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"type": "temporal", "field": "date"},
    "y": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "value"}
  }
}
```

[image]

If you use a custom transformation to display the first character, then at the year transition the first character will be `"2"`.

If you want to control exactly how the date is formatted, you can do that by specifying a [d3-date-format](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format) code in `axis.format`:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"date": "2020-10-31T00:00:00", "value": 9},
      {"date": "2020-11-30T00:00:00", "value": 10},
      {"date": "2020-12-31T00:00:00", "value": 11},
      {"date": "2021-01-31T00:00:00", "value": 12},
      {"date": "2021-02-28T00:00:00", "value": 13}
    ]
  },
  "mark": "line",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"type": "temporal", "field": "date", "axis": {"format": "%b"}},
    "y": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "value"}
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @jakevdp. I appreciate the quick reply and the solution.

Added format to my axis object and it worked straightaway.